# Turning water off to house for a vacation, does furnace need to go off as well?

Tags: water, heating, water-heater

I am going away for a week, I want to shut off all water to my home. I have an oil furnace, with a separate water boiler (connected to the oil furnace - there is no gas in the house). It is summer in my area. Do I need to turn my furnace or water boiler off? What could go wrong if I leave the furnace / boiler on?

Thanks

Comment: why are you asking?  ....questions that seek an opinion are frowned upon here.

Comment: @jsotola I don't understand your confusion - I want to know if one is supposed to turn off their water boiler if turning off water to the entire house - is this such a strange thing to ask?

Comment: i thought that a water boiler for house heating is a closed loop .... anyway, something could always go wrong .... if the furnace is turned off then that is one less thing to go wrong

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It looks like "Reg" and "user3203425" are both your accounts; please pick one and use it. And, @jsotola is trying to help you, and asked for clarification, which is a helpful thing to do. You should check out our Help section to learn more about how we work.

Answer (score 1):

If the water is shut, should water level drop, e.g. if an outside faucet were turned on, it's likely a water heater or boiler would be damaged.

If plumbing is sound, I'd not shut the water for just one week in summer, since it's unlikely pipes would freeze. For a [long-term winter vacation](https://inspectapedia.com/plumbing/Winterize_Heat_Off.php), if turning off heat, you'd need to drain the plumbing, dish- and clothes-washer, flush toilets, put potable antifreeze in drains, etc.